# Multiple App files

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to merge two applications I've created. A website built with React and the dashboard for once logged into the website.
Problem is they both feature a app.js with different styling and components.

I've tried changing the dashboard app.js to appDashHome.js and have it only load on an onClick via the login box. However because it's not on the app.js as a element tag it's not displaying.

I'm guessing because it's not being called to render via the index.js, however I can't have two tags there as it won't work.
I've got this in my index.js currently:

```
ReactDOM.render((
 <BrowserRouter>
   <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
     <App />
   </LocaleProvider>
 </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm using React Router, so creating a seperate page isn't a problem, it's just the websites app.js has header and footer components that the dashboard doesn't need. So how do I create two app.js that can work in conjunction together? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Also I don't want the dashboard to display on the home page (The only way I can get it to work at the moment) I only want it to load away from the website via an onClick on the login box. And I don't want it to inherit anything from the current app.js. HELP!

Comment: create new file, and set the routing to your desired output